# Guess the sum of several variables is a fixed value, how to predict this fixed value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I know that the dataframe has three columns (named A, B, and C) and now I want to predict

**k1×A+k2×B+k3×C = a fixed value D**

A, B, C are known, and k1,k2,k3,D are not known(needed to be predicted).
How to predict these three coefficients and this fixed value?

The details are as follows:

```
file_path = 'input/CharacterData.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
five_star_data = df[df[' star '] == 5] # Choose the five-star characters
X = five_star_data[['生命值', '攻击力', '防御力']]  # Here, I choose three three dimensions about the five-star characters. And'生命值', '攻击力', '防御力' means HP, ATK, DEF in English
```

and I want to predict :

**k1×HP +k2×ATK +k3×DEF = a fixed value D**

It must have some error, **how to judge whether the error is large or small**?

In addition, Please bear with me that my English ability and machine learning level are not very good.

**First, I try to set the D to a fixed value of 1:**

```
X = five_star_data[['生命值', '攻击力', '防御力']]
y_value = 1
y = pd.DataFrame(np.full((X.shape[0], 1), y_value))
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)
print(lin_reg.intercept_)  # [1.]
print(lin_reg.coef_)  # [[0. 0. 0.]]
```

I think, because X(HP, ATK, DEF) is changed, but y is fixed.So the LinearRegression model think the coefficients of A,B,C should be 0 and the intercept is exactly 1.

**Second, I choose the HP('生命值') as y, and drop HP in X.** Like this:

```
X = five_star_data[['生命值', '攻击力', '防御力']]
X_1 = X.drop(["生命值"], axis=1)
y = five_star_data['生命值']
y = -y
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_1, y)
print(lin_reg.intercept_)  # -9252.295197338677
print(lin_reg.coef_)  # [ 5.60260844 -6.41900625]
```

It can get the result, but I don't know if it is suitable.

Yes, I change the question to:
-HP = k1×ATK + K2×EF + D.

I think it can be changed to the original question:
HP + k1×ATK  + K2×DEF  = -D.